# Can't access image after upload

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use this code to upload an image to the server:

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploaded"), fileName);
file.SaveAs(path);
```

Everything goes fine and I can see that the image is uploaded when I check with FileZilla. But later when I try to access the image like this:

```
@{ var path = "/Content/Uploaded/" + item.ImageName; }
<img src="@Url.Content(path)" width="200"/>
```

I get

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. You
>   do not have permission to view this directory or page using the
>   credentials that you supplied.

How do I get around this? If I delete the file with FileZilla and add the same file manually after it works so I guess it have to be that "file.SaveAs(path)" put some permissions on the file that don't work and not the folder.

Comment: You seem to be using a path relative to the application root directory "~/Content..." when uploading, but when attempting read you are using a path relative to the current directory "/Content...". Assuming you are in the Views folder in MVC, this will not get you to the same directory. Output the value of "path" in the view and make sure it is going to the desired path. Url.Content() can also accept a path relative to the root with "~/...", so try using that.

Comment: I have changed around with that too, but it don't seems to be any problem with the path. Because it save to the correct folder when I check FileZilla. And when I delete the image and add it manually with FileZilla in the same folder the link in the view work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that there is a difference between `~/Content/Uploaded` and `/Content/Uploaded`

That s your problem.

I usually dont prefer using `~` for convenience.

Take a look at the source code of the page as well. what do you see for img tag?

Comment: As I already answered, I tried with both. It don't seems to be any problem with the path as other images in the same folder that I put there manually works.It's just images that I upload through the site that don't work (and I checked that they are in the correct folder).

Comment: I just tried it and got access denied. And this error: "ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via <identity impersonate="true"/>, the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user. "

Comment: well you need to provide read access to that folder. you should be able to do it via some control panel your hosting provider gives you. otherwise give them a call

Comment: Guess I have to do that. I just find it weird that I can read images that I uploaded through filezilla, but not images uploaded through the site (even when they are in the same folder). But thanks anyway.